# Brick support angle iron too tight to shingles to replace shingles

Tags: brick, shingles, angle

We have a front garage with bedroom over half of the garage, with brick facing. The brick support angle is right on top of the shingles and does not allow shingle replacement. Can the old shingles be pulled out from under the steel angle and an angle flashing be installed - how can this be done. It is unsafe to pull the bottom row of bricks/angle and put flashing in sections.

---

We are replacing the garage shingles which tuck underneath the brick shelf/angle (i.e. need to get the old shingles out). Since we need to either reuse the existing flashing under the brick angle or replace it, I am looking for a method to carefully tear out the shingles to minimize damage to the existing flashing. The undesirable alternatives are to demo/replace the entire brick wall, or possibly local demo/replace the garage deck/shingle only under that edge (under the brick). Although there is a gap in the brick above, we are not aware of any leaks.  There is a brick repair required in one spot as well. Thanks.[image]

Comment: Are you trying to replace all the shingles? Trying to just replace the flashing? Do you have a leak you're investigating?

Comment: Is there flashing now? The situation calls for "step flashing", which is a series of steel shingles interleaved with the asphalt shingles. They can often be reused if tear-off is done carefully. Otherwise, no, you probably can't retrofit flashing. Please post photos and describe your plans in more detail.

Comment: Hi! You have a couple of user accounts, one registered and one unregistered. There are advantages to [merging them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts) and [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: @FredricShope the shingles in that pic look pretty well worn. I'm guess it's just simply time for a new roof...

Comment: I would venture a guess that if you started to pull the shingles up, you'd find they were _not_ nailed underneath the brick. So long as there's flashing, if you were careful, you would be able to slide new shingles in between the layers of flashing. You would start nailing at the edge of the brick and count on the brick itself to keep the ends from blowing up. `</speculation>`

Comment: We are replacing the garage shingles - poor shape but no leak of which we are aware. Existing flashing cannot be seen - possibly insert step flashing in sections. Maybe I will pick a spot (e.g. that can be sealed afterward) and try to pull out the shingles.  If stuck it will be very expensive to fix (e.g. bricklayer). Thanks.